# Replacing jQuery each with for

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, each

I've been using $.each to do iterations for a while now, but I keep on hearing people say to use native JS for to do loops. I'm very concerned about performance but I am not sure if it's always possible to replace $.each with for in a meaningful way.

So my questions are, is it possible to always replace $.each with for, and if not what's the rule of thumb for when it can be done and when it cannot.

I have an each like this:

```
 $this.find("div.class").each(function (){
  var $thisparent = $(this).parent();

  if (condition) {          
   $(this).prepend($thisparent.text());
  }

  if (condition2) {          
   $(this).prepend($thisparent.text());
  }

 });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what jQuery does with `.each`, *basically*:

```
$.fn.each = function(callback) {
    var i, length = this.length;
    for(i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        callback.call(this[i]);
    }
};
```

So it's not hard to substitute your anonymous function's 'contents' with the `callback.call` call.  Just be sure to replace `this` with a temporary with the jQuery object.

Converting your supplied code:

```
var foo = $this.find("div.class"),
    fooLength = foo.length,
    i,
    $thisparent;

for (i = 0; i < fooLength; ++i) {
    $thisparent = $(foo[i]).parent();

    if (condition) {          
        $(foo[i]).prepend($thisparent.text());
    }

    if (condition2) {          
        $(foo[i]).prepend($thisparent.text());
    }
}
```

For additional (potential) speed, cache `foo[i]` into a temporary. too, and assign `$thisparent` only when needed.  If `condition` and `condition2` are mutually exclusive, use a single `if (condition || condition2)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you please provide an example?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much, :) great answer and thanks for increasing my understanding. Can you demonstrate how to use a single if? Also what if I have half a dozen mutually exclusive conditions.

Comment: @Mark, Read up on the || operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Answer (score 5):

Someone compared the performance of `for` and `$.each`:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/javascript-for-loop-vs-jquery-each.html

Comment: So apparently you only take a substantial performance hit with large arrays. Good to know.

Comment: I think the reason behind this is the overhead of function calls, as jQuery's `each` code isn't that heavy at all.

Comment: @Joel: Well, it's substantial in the sense that jQuery takes twice as long (with array size of one million). But the difference is only 600ms which is nothing, really.

Comment: But as we all know: Many a mickle makes a muckle. ^^

Comment: @anddoutoi - +1 for "Many a mickle makes a muckle"

Comment: Would the speed of the jQuery each depend on how much info needs to be stashed in a closure for each iteration?